# Really weird "Data conversion error"

Tags: database, h2

I'm in front of a really weird `Data conversion error` when i'm trying to insert a row in a table in my H2 database (version 1.4.182).

I don't know if i'm missing something or if it's a real bug, this is the table structure :

[image]

The error and the insert query :

[image]

If you want to try :

```
INSERT INTO PAPPU_USERS(ID, CREATED, EMAIL, FIRSTNAME, GENDER, JOB, 
  LASTNAME, LOGIN, PASSWORD, PHONE1, PHONE2, SA, UPDATED, DEFAULTPLACE_ID, 
  DEFAULTVISITTYPE_ID, STRUCTURE_RECORD_ID) VALUES 
( 'base_1', null, null, '', null, null, 
  '', 'pappu', 'pappu', null, null, FALSE, null, 'base_1', 
  1, 'base_1' );
```

Many of the other tables of my schema have the same structure (i mean, with a varchar primary key column and a custom sequence id by default) and everything is ok when I insert a row on them.

**------------ SOLVED ----------------**

I'm using Hibernate which generate the database structure.
In the other tables with the same structure, I don't use the auto increment generated by the default sequence (cause i need to prefix the value).

For this table, I forgot to declare this custom sequence. So, the value "base_1" doesn't corespond with the default sequence (1, 2, 3, 4...).

Comment: defaultvsittype_id is int but 'base_1' is a string

Comment: The value for defaultvsittype_id is 1 !

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I misread the order

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace please (click on the error message to get it)?